# Смена ModelBackend на AllowAllUsersModelBackend

Tags: python, django, авторизация

Всем привет. Пытаюсь реализовать вход на сайт неактивных пользователей. Из документации стало понятно что нужно сменить backend авторизации и заглушить confirm_login_allowed в AuthenticationForm. Подскажите, что делаю не так?

forms.py:

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        pass
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл прописать урл.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(form_class=MyAuthenticationForm), name='login'),
```

]